# "Setup cannot continue because a required file is either corrupted or not available [...]" error during Windows 7 Professional installation

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer

I encounter the following error during Windows installation:

```
Setup cannot continue because a required file is either
corrupted or not available.  Run Setup again from the original
source disc or download location.
```

This error appears during the `Installing Windows...` phase, `Expanding Windows files` process.

The interesting part is that I only receive this while installing Windows from an USB flash drive with a capacity larger than 8 GB (I tried with 16GB and 64GB). The same image burned to a USB flash drive of 8GB works fine (no errors encountered).

Is there any such limitation when installing Windows from a flash drive?

Are there any ways to debug this further more, in order to understand what file/process is actually causing it?

Answer (score -1):

Step 1
Click the "Start" button and then click "Programs" at the bottom of your screen.

Step 2
Click the "Accessories" button and go over to the "Command Prompt" option.

Step 3
Right-click "Command Prompt" and then select the "Run as administrator" option from the menu.

Step 4
Enter your administrator password into the field that appears on the screen and click the "OK" button to enter the command prompt.

Step 5
Type "sfc /scannow" into the command prompt and press the "Enter" button.

Wait for the computer to scan your system files and replace the installer files as needed.